# AppendMenu() font change, c++

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I develop a c++ application with MinGW compiler.
I changed the CreateWindow() functions default font, something like this:

```
HFONT font;
font = CreateFont(15, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Tahoma");

HWND btn;
btn = CreateWindowEx(BS_PUSHBUTTON, "BUTTON", "Title",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)ID_BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            0);
SendMessage(btn, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) font, TRUE);
```

But I created menu:

```
HMENU hMenu, hSubMenu;
hMenu = CreateMenu();
hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenuW(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_FILE_OPEN_BTN, "Open" );
AppendMenuW(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu,  "File" );
```

But I dont know how to change the font in the AppendMenuW(), can anybody help me?

Comment: In short, you can't, unless you implement [owner-drawn menu items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Setting_Fonts_for_Menu_Item_Text_Strings).

Comment: Thanks but I am a beginner, Could you tell me more detail?

Comment: That's quite a complex matter, to be honest. The link in my previous comment will lead you to a code sample with explanations on the structures you have to implement and the messages you have to handle.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to change the font? What's wrong with using the same font every other window on the system uses? Users don't like applications that look too different. Like Frederic says, this is not only a difficult thing to do, I'd say it's rather pointless. There's no way that owner-drawn menus are worth the effort just to get a custom font. That offers no value to the user.